# Date and date range based member-only downloads

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions, woocommerce-memberships

Scratching my head with a specific setup for member-only content (currently using Woo Memberships and Woo Subscriptions).

The project has a large number of downloadable products which are available for purchase as one-offs. So far so good :)
However, those downloads should be available for free for paid members - a bit more tricky.

Besides that, only those downloads that are published during the membership period should be available for free - every product has a custom field that contains month and year the product belongs to.

For example, if I'm an active member since Jan 2019 - I get free access to downloads for Jan 2019, Feb 2019 and so on.
If I used to be a member from Apr 2018 till Dec 2018 - I get free access to downloads for Apr 2018, May 2018 and so on.

Any tips how to build such setup? Should I consider EDD (or maybe something else) instead of Woo?  I'm almost ready to begin modifying https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscription-downloads/ for this, but thought maybe someone else has done anything similar before?

Comment: if ```file_meta_date``` in range (```start_subscription```, ```end_subscription```)  can be downloaded?

Comment: How do I make a downloadable product free to download w/o checkout?

Comment: I guess you could add a direct download link in the product template then make it available only if @Sky conditions are filled.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party on this one, but I think that a plugin called [S2Member](https://s2member.com/) might be really good for this case.